# How to get the result of Runtime.getRuntime().exec directly

Tags: android, root

I'm working on a rooted android device. I'm trying to capture the screen and store the result in `Bitmap` for later usage.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();
path += "/img.png";

Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + path).getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();

final Bitmap x = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

What I'm doing here is naming a path for a new image and capturing the screen using the command `/system/bin/screencap -p FILEPATH`. Then I read the image I stored in that file and use it in the bitmap.

My problem with my current code is that it's slow(not suitable for a real-time application). I'm now trying to make it faster. Instead of saving the captured picture into file and then reading it again from the program, I want to read it directly from the result of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`

In the description of the command [screencap](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp#L55), I found that I can use it without specifying the output file name, and in this case the results will be printed to stdout.

I tried several codes to read the result byte array to use it directly in my code

```
final Bitmap x = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(resultArrayByte, 0, resultArrayByte.length);
```

but none of the codes worked with me.

How can I use `sh`'s input/output streams to get the result byte array directly without saving the output into a file then loading it again?

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-screenshot-library/wikis/Usage.wiki), in this link you can find a library called ASL

a lot of questions in this post, i'm confused :)

i hope this link is useful for your requirements.

Comment: URLs change, it would be better if you posted a little summary of what's on the target page in case the link breaks, so that someone can find it by title.